# Cursor moving to start of the box in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor library in my module and there is a textbox above which there is a button icon on clicking the button the below code is triggered

```
    var onclick= function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(isPickerVisible()) {
            closePicker();
        } else {
            showPicker();
        }
        // base.editor.execCommand('quicktext');
    };
```

If I'm writing a text on the textbox and then clicking on the button, the cursor is jumping to the start of the text.
This is happening on safari browser only it's working fine on chrome.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+picker+safari+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.